# Glitch, lag while playing videos and games

Tags: windows-8, video, performance, graphics-card, lag

I have a Windows 8.1 laptop (Intel i5, 6GB RAM, 2GB Nvidia graphics card). I'm using VLC player for playing videos. While playing games or watching videos, there's lag. I don't know why, but when I check the Task Manager, "Windows system service" or something else uses 100% disk, and then everything slows down. It occurs once a minute, maybe this causes the lag. I installed Avast Internet Security antivirus. When I start my laptop, Avast takes 100% disk usage for about one minute and then slows down. Some search results from Google said Windows 8 uses the disk a lot. Is there a way to stop this lag?

Comment: Please define the "lag" better, reduced frame rate? or slow data transfer? Slow net responces? or something else?

Comment: Lag means while playing videos or games, screen pauses for about half a second but sound is working. After half a second things goes to normal again

Comment: Ok, because it sounded some like it might be a grafics driver issue, but the lag your describing does sound more like another task, and/or transfers over the bus or ram I/O.  Check also the resource monitor.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds a lot like [this issue here (This may be of help).](https://superuser.com/questions/659201/too-much-disk-i-o-on-windows/700989#700989)

You're not the only one; this seems to happen to a lot of people. I know that System Updates in the background can run disk I/O up to large levels, as can antivirus scans. Not too sure on the reason for these spikes though; it happens to me quite often too.

Comment: So whats the solution

Comment: To be honest, I have yet to find one. From reading around, it appears to be just trying to find whatever process is running with a high disk read/write rate and killing it if it is safe to do so.

For me usually the problem stops within 5 to 10 minutes of the computer starting up; so in my case I think a service is running on startup that shouldn't, even though My Startup programs are all disabled. I would take a look [here](http://superuser.com/questions/650156/windows-8-disk-usage-at-100-nothing-responds). Try to look through resource monitor to identify any rogue processes.